# reading and accessing text written in jTextArea using jForm

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextarea, jform

How can I read text written in jTextArea and do any operation on it like edit & search etc. 
For example I have a paragraph of 4,5 line written in jTextArea and I want to search a word from that para using in JForm using Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Use : 
      textarea1.getText();
Will return the text then use StrinhTokenizer that allow you to break string into token then compare them with your search keyword  http://www.javatpoint.com/string-tokenizer-in-java